# calling kern_path during mount process

Tags: linux-kernel, mount-point

I'm trying to get devt of mountpoint (path*) in one of the LSM hooks.
Assuming I have the following mount:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p5 is mounted to /mnt/photos
```

I would expect that calling

```
kern_path("/mnt/photos", ...)
```

will return a `struct path` with `path.mnt->mnt_sb->s_dev = 0x0b300005` since `/dev/mmcblk0p5` is 179:5,
but I always get 0x0b300002 (i.e. 179:2) - which is the root-fs device.
Only after mounting again `/dev/mmcblk0p5` to `/mnt/photos`, `kern_path` returns 0x0b300005.

Why is that? How can I fix it?
It happens with both kernel 4.14 and 5.15.

some more info,
after 1st mount, printing address of `path.mnt->mnt_sb` is the same as of `"/" (0x0b300002)`.
after 2nd mount, printing address of `path.mnt->mnt_sb` is different.
i guess that `mnt_sb` is being updated sometime between the 1st and the 2nd mount.
so, when it happens? how can i get notification/hook after this update?

Comment: I fixed the second hexa value because you put 0x0b300005 twice...

Comment: Can you show the mount commands that you are using? I guess that /mnt is on the rootfs (located in /dev/mmcblk0p2). But what, about the subdirectory photos? Is it in the rootfs (/dev/mmcblk0p2) or in /dev/mmcblk0p5?

Comment: mount command: sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p5 /mnt/photos.
in case i do umount, and then mount, i get 0x0b300002.
then, if i do mount again (without umount), i get 0x0b300005 as expected.
it seems like the /mnt/photos is not completely mounted on 1st time.
i tried to call kern_path in several LSM hooks (sb_mount, sb_kern_mount, ...) but this problem happens in all of them.